# how to update row based on value of another row sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i would like to know what is the best way to update a row based on another row , lets say for example i have table like this:

```
ID   |   NAME    |  VALUE  |
----------------------------
 1   |   a  |   10   |
 2   |   b  |  NULL  |
 3   |   c  |  NULL  |
 4   |   d  |  NULL  |
 5   |   a  |   10   |
 6   |   b  |  NULL  |
 7   |   c  |  NULL  |
 8   |   d  |  NULL  |
 9   |   a  |  NULL  |
.
.
.
```

now i need an UPDATE query that will compare all the rows with the name = d to rows with name = a and if row with name = a have in value = 10 then row with name = d will get value = 10 and then row with name = a value will set to NULL and if not then not. its like i need to switch between the values of the rows (a to d , b to c , c to d , d to a) in that order. in every 4 rows(a,b,c,d) will allways be only one row that value is not null.

i hope it was clear.
thanks!!

Comment: I think a better table structure would help a lot. For Example ID|a|b|c|d this would allow you to compare along the row for any given id. In it's current form i know that name d id 4 should be compared to name a id 1 but the sql logic for the databse would need to be unecessarily convoluted to make the correct comparisons and maintain

Comment: Please provide desired results as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I fully understand what you are trying to achieve here, but here's something to start a discussion:

```
--Create sample data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp;
CREATE TABLE #temp (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(50), [VALUE] INT);
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 1, 'a', 10;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 2, 'b', NULL;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 3, 'c', NULL;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 4, 'd', NULL;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 5, 'a', 10;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 6, 'b', NULL;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 7, 'c', NULL;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 8, 'd', NULL;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 9, 'a', NULL;
```

All this does is to swap a's and d's around if there is a value in the a's:

```
WITH Best AS (
    SELECT NAME, MAX([VALUE]) AS MAXVALUE FROM #temp GROUP BY NAME)
UPDATE
    t
SET
    [VALUE] = 
        CASE 
            WHEN t.NAME = 'a' AND b.MAXVALUE IS NOT NULL THEN NULL
            WHEN t.NAME = 'd' AND b.MAXVALUE IS NOT NULL THEN b.MAXVALUE 
        END
FROM
    #temp t
    CROSS JOIN Best b 
WHERE
    t.NAME IN ('a', 'd')
    AND b.NAME = 'a';

SELECT * FROM #temp;
```

On completion I can see that all the a values have moved to the d rows.  That doesn't cope with b to c, c to d, etc. though.  Is this anything like what you want?

---

Now it looks like you actually need each group of four rows to be handled separately, so this might work better?

```
WITH Groups AS (
    SELECT ID, (ID - 1) / 4 AS group_id, NAME, [VALUE] FROM #temp),
Best AS (
    SELECT group_id, NAME, MAX([VALUE]) AS MAXVALUE FROM Groups GROUP BY group_id, NAME)
UPDATE
    t
SET
    [VALUE] = 
        CASE 
            WHEN t.NAME = 'a' AND b.MAXVALUE IS NOT NULL THEN NULL
            WHEN t.NAME = 'd' AND b.MAXVALUE IS NOT NULL THEN b.MAXVALUE 
        END
FROM
    #temp t
    INNER JOIN Groups g ON g.ID = t.ID
    INNER JOIN Best b ON b.group_id = g.group_id
WHERE
    t.NAME IN ('a', 'd')
    AND b.NAME = 'a';
```

---

Here's a new query for you, now I finally think I understand what this is supposed to do.  First here's my understanding of what you actually want:

- you have data that is ordered by an ID;
- the data is organised into groups of 4, starting at "a", then "b", then "c", then "d";
- for each group of 4 items find the single item that has a non-NULL value;
- move this one forward, i.e. if the a value is there move it to b, etc.
- the d value moves back round to a again;
- each group is independent of the others.

I created a slightly different set of data to show this working in practice:

```
--Create sample data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp;
CREATE TABLE #temp (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(50), [VALUE] INT);
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 1, 'a', 10;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 2, 'b', NULL;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 3, 'c', NULL;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 4, 'd', NULL;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 5, 'a', NULL;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 6, 'b', NULL;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 7, 'c', NULL;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 8, 'd', 5;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 9, 'a', NULL;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 10, 'b', 90;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 11, 'c', NULL;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 12, 'd', NULL;
```

...and here's my amended query:

```
WITH Groups AS (
    SELECT 
        (ID - 1) / 4 AS group_id,
        ID, 
        NAME, 
        [VALUE] 
    FROM 
        #temp),
Best AS (
    SELECT 
        group_id, 
        ID,
        NAME,
        [VALUE]
    FROM 
        Groups
    WHERE
        [VALUE] IS NOT NULL)
UPDATE
    t
SET
    [VALUE] = 
        CASE 
            WHEN t.NAME = 'a' AND b.NAME = 'a' THEN NULL
            WHEN t.NAME = 'a' AND b.NAME = 'd' THEN b.[VALUE]
            WHEN t.NAME = 'b' AND b.NAME = 'b' THEN NULL
            WHEN t.NAME = 'b' AND b.NAME = 'a' THEN b.[VALUE]
            WHEN t.NAME = 'c' AND b.NAME = 'c' THEN NULL
            WHEN t.NAME = 'c' AND b.NAME = 'b' THEN b.[VALUE]
            WHEN t.NAME = 'd' AND b.NAME = 'd' THEN NULL
            WHEN t.NAME = 'd' AND b.NAME = 'c' THEN b.[VALUE]
        END
FROM
    #temp t
    INNER JOIN Groups g ON g.ID = t.ID
    INNER JOIN Best b ON b.group_id = g.group_id;
```

So my data starts off like this:

```
ID  NAME    VALUE
1   a   10
2   b   NULL
3   c   NULL
4   d   NULL
5   a   NULL
6   b   NULL
7   c   NULL
8   d   5
9   a   NULL
10  b   90
11  c   NULL
12  d   NULL
```

...and when I run the UPDATE query:

```
ID  NAME    VALUE
1   a   NULL
2   b   10
3   c   NULL
4   d   NULL
5   a   5
6   b   NULL
7   c   NULL
8   d   NULL
9   a   NULL
10  b   NULL
11  c   90
12  d   NULL
```

If I run the query again then everything moves one more step:

```
ID  NAME    VALUE
1   a   NULL
2   b   NULL
3   c   10
4   d   NULL
5   a   NULL
6   b   5
7   c   NULL
8   d   NULL
9   a   NULL
10  b   NULL
11  c   NULL
12  d   90
```

If this still isn't what you want then either show me what you think the values should be after the first/ second iteration, or come up with a new before -> after example in your question.

---

Hopefully this will be the final attempt :D

```
WITH Groups AS (
    SELECT 
        (ID - 1) / 4 AS group_id,
        ID, 
        NAME, 
        [VALUE] 
    FROM 
        #temp),
Best AS (
    SELECT 
        group_id, 
        ID,
        NAME,
        [VALUE]
    FROM 
        Groups
    WHERE
        [VALUE] IS NOT NULL)
UPDATE
    t
SET
    [VALUE] = 
        CASE 
            --a to d
            WHEN t.NAME = 'd' AND b.NAME = 'a' THEN b.[VALUE]

            --b to c
            WHEN t.NAME = 'c' AND b.NAME = 'b' THEN b.[VALUE] 

            --c to d (seems wrong?)
            WHEN t.NAME = 'd' AND b.NAME = 'c' THEN b.[VALUE]

            --d to a
            WHEN t.NAME = 'a' AND b.NAME = 'd' THEN b.[VALUE]

            --Set the moving item to NULL
            WHEN t.NAME = b.NAME THEN NULL
        END
FROM
    #temp t
    INNER JOIN Groups g ON g.ID = t.ID
    INNER JOIN Best b ON b.group_id = g.group_id;
```

Comment: i did it on my server and it worked for the first time when a hade value 10 in row a and NULL in row d but when i tried to do this on the same rows 1-4 but with value NULL in row a it still put 10 in row d.

Comment: ok this problem is solved , now there is another problem :
i tried to put in row 1 value 10 and in row 7 value 10 all the other rows 2,3,4,5,6,8 have NULL , when i compilate row 1 got NULL , row 4 got 10 and row 8 got 10 wich is not good because row 8 need to be depandant not on row 1 but on row 5 and row 5 didnt hade value 10.

Comment: From this it sounds like you actually want the update to work on batches of four rows at a time, so rows 1-4 are a group, then rows 5-8, etc.?  If so then my script won't work, as it looks across then entire set each time.

Comment: much better now only one more problem : if in row a value is NULL then row d gets NULL TO.

Comment: I think I know how this should work now, here's another try

Comment: first of all i would like to thank you for the help and the effort that you are doing is amazing!
now the last try went wrong because i dont wont to MOVE the value to the next ID i want to make switches between A to d,then b to c, then c to b , then d to a.
so the previous query was much much better he had only ONE SMALL problem - if A value is NULL and i am moving values of A to D then he moves the NULL to D and this is not good .

Comment: In your original question you said c goes to d, but now you are saying c goes to b, which actually makes more sense.  If the latter is true then you will need to just change the CASE statement that I noted looks wrong, changing t.NAME = 'd' to t.NAME = 'b'

Comment: the last one worked perfectly!!! you are a genius!! thanks you so much :)

Comment: Cool, glad we got there in the end.  I was going to ask what this is actually for, but now I'm not sure I really want to know ;D

Comment: hhh so the story is like this : i developed surveys for users in web client with html javascript and connection to database, i build 2 tables in sql table 1 was the questions : each row is 1 question. 
and another table for the 4 unswers for  exemple:
how was the survice   1.bad 2.good 3.very good 4.excelent .

Comment: and the unswer table is 1 row for each unswer wich means that every 4 rows have the same key for every 1 quastion. everthing worked fine but i did ONE big mistake - the html sended the wrong unswers for example :user picked 4.excelent as an unswer the code was sending 1.bad . hhh wich means that for the last 3 mounths all the unswers were opposite :)